# Does SEO ranking gets affected if I run a split URL test on our product detail page (PDP) using Visual Web Optimizer (VWO)

Tags: seo, google-ranking, a-b-testing, split-testing, visual-website-optimizer

We are trying to run a vwo test for our pdp page.I created a test in VWO where  URL `www.example.com/products/productid` will get redirected to `www.example.com/productid?isVWOVersion=true` for 50% users.

Based on the request param `isVWOVersio`n I will decide whether new PDP content needs to be displayed vs old one.

Below is the jsp structure -> `index.jsp` -> `isVWOVersion = true` then include `pdpNew.jsp` else include `pdpOld.jsp`

Will my SEO ranking get affected? Does Google sees two versions of PDP as duplicate content? Do I need to add `noindex` meta tag
`<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>` to `pdpNew.jsp` to avoid SEO ranking issues due to duplicate content?

Comment: Hi Stephen, i deleted the other question. Does google treat www.mysite.com/productid?isVWOVersion=true and www.mysite.com/productid as two different urls and will see them as two pages having duplicate contents causing SEO ranking issue?

Comment: Yes, those are two different URLs to Google.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.                                                                                                  so that means i will need to add a no index, no follow meta tag on jsp corresponding to www.example.com/productid?isVWOVersion=true to avoid any duplicate content issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've run split-URL tests like this ourselves, and haven't seen any fall in SERPs. Some customers had lingering doubts, so here's what we did after scouring the web:

- Choose two pages; the control and the variation
- Add canonical tag to both pages... pointing to the control page
- Run split test for 17 days

Result: The control page did not fall out of Google rankings.

(I work for VWO.)